# How to get show create table in Big Query web UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get Create table script for an existing Table basically DDL from web UI or something similar to Show create table . I have googled couldn't find anything relevant

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Cool news! Launched today, now you can get the DDL from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Here is the example from [Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables):

```
SELECT
 table_name, ddl
FROM
 `bigquery-public-data`.census_bureau_usa.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
 table_name="population_by_zip_2010"
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

I don't think you can retrieve a `CREATE` statement from an existing table in BigQuery, but you can do:

-Obtain the table schema:

```
bq show --schema --format=prettyjson [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] > ./schema.json
```

-Create a new table from the schema file:

```
bq mk --table --description [DESCRIPTION] [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] ./schema.json
```

You can review the additional settings for table creation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition).

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119245739) to have equivalent of [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html) MySQL command. As you can see from the comment#2 from Elliott, it's not likely to be implemented. However you can "recreate a CREATE TABLE statement using INFORMATION_SCHEMA", for more detail, please check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/35906063) public issue.